# if condition not being met when should be

Tags: javascript

```
var userchoice;
var compchoice = parseFloat(Math.ceil(Math.random()*10));
console.log(compchoice);





function guess () {
    if (compchoice === document.getElementById("userguess").value) {
        alert("You guessed it!");
        location.reload()
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("userguess").value > compchoice) {
        alert("That was a little high, try again")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("userguess").value < compchoice) {
        alert("That was a little low, try again")
    }
    else if (isNaN(document.getElementById("userguess").value)) {
        alert("Guess a number bro")
    }

}
```

So here's my code. I'm a beginner just messing around with concepts. Now here's the problem, if you guess the number correctly, the first `if` statement in `guess()` should run, but it doesn't. The other `else if`'s run, so I'm stumped as to what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using the wrong equality operator for this (don't use ===, which checks for object identity)

Comment: I would try with integers first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return a string:

```js
document.getElementById("userguess").value
```

This will return a number:

```js
parseFloat(Math.ceil(Math.random()*10))
```

Since the types are different, `===` will return `false`. Some solutions:

- Compare using `==`
- Convert the string to a number: `+str`
- Convert the number to a string: `''+num`

Comment: But > and < dont need to be converted to strings?

Comment: @AnthonyDeGennaro If both operands are strings, the comparison is lexicographic. Otherwise, they are converted to numbers, and the comparison is numerical. I think you want numerical, which is the current one because `compchoice` is not a string. See [`<`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), [`==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), [`===`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

`compchoice === document.getElementById("userguess").value` is evaluating to false because the `===` operator is comparing a `float` with a `string`.

You can fix this by either parsing the user guess to a float or using the `==` operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

[The `===` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) doesn't just check value equality, but also type equality.  So this will be false:

```
compchoice === document.getElementById("userguess").value
```

because `compchoice` is numeric data and `.value` is sting data.  You can most immediately fix the issue by using the non-strict comparison operator:

```
compchoice == document.getElementById("userguess").value
```

This will compare values without concern for types, so things like `1` and `'1'` will compare as equal.